# Can I write "having been developing ... for about four years"?

Tags: clauses, participles

Is the following usage of participle clause correct?

> I have a good knowledge of C++/Qt, *having been developing with them for about 4 years.*

Here, it's meant that the speaker has been developing with C++/Qt for already 4 years, and he/she continues developing with it now.

Comment: I think it's okay, but it might be a little better to front the participle clause: *Having been developing with C++/Qt for about 4 year, I have a good knowledge of them.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of the participial perfect is, well, perfect!

But I'm a little dubious about two other pieces of your sentence:

- Joining C++ and Qt with a slash is, no doubt, industry-standard, but it defines the two entities as a single complex. This may cause a momentary confusion when the reader reaches the pronoun *them* and casts about for a plural referent. You would do better to recast this as *C++ and Qt*.
- In this context, *developing* is ambiguous: it may be transitive *develop*, referring to the projects you have brought to completion, or it may be intransitive *develop*, referring to your personal *development*. You will help your reader by adding a direct object: *having been developing substantial applications with them...*.

These are very minor points; but your job as a writer is to make it as easy as possible for your reader to understand what you mean, even if it costs a couple of extra words.

Comment: "having been developing...." is not a participle clause.  I think it should be a participle phrase.  Please correct me if I am wrong.  Thanks

Comment: @Pupu It is a distinction without a difference. Traditional grammar treated as 'clauses' only constituents headed by finite verbs; today we tend to call constituents headed by non-finite verbs 'clauses', too, because we 'derive' them from finite clauses.